# Batch rotate PDF files with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I've been working on a code to batch rotate PDF files inside a folder, but I can't find a way to iterate and change the destination folder of the rotated file.

My intention is to save the new file with the same name in another folder.

```py
from os import listdir

from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

# Collect files
root = "C:\z_PruebPy\pdf"
archs = []
for x in listdir(root):
    archs.append(root + x)

# Batch rotate
for arch in archs:
    pdf_in = open(arch, "rb")
    reader = PdfReader(pdf_in)
    writer = PdfWriter()

    for page in reader.pages:
        page.rotate_clockwise(270)
        writer.add_page(page)

    with open(arch, "wb") as pdf_out:  # ????????
        writer.write(pdf_out)
    pdf_in.close()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to give PdfFileWriter a file pointer to the new location.
Also you don't need to create a list and iterate on the list, just iterate on `os.listdir` results.
Finally you had unused variables, like `loc`.
I cleaned your code a bit.

So this should work, assuming you create the output folder :

```py
from os import listdir
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

input_dir  = "C:\\z_PruebPy\\pdf\\"
output_dir = "C:\\z_PruebPy\\output_pdf\\"

for fname in listdir(input_dir):
    if not fname.endswith(".pdf"):  # ignore non-pdf files
        continue
    reader = PdfReader(input_dir + fname)
    writer = PdfWriter()
    for page in reader.pages:
        # page.rotate_clockwise(270) # (before pypdf3.0 - deprecated - thanks to Maciejg for the update)
        page.rotate(270)
        writer.add_page(page)
    with open(output_dir + fname, "wb") as pdf_out:
        writer.write(pdf_out)
```

Comment: Thanks!!, exactly what I wanted

Comment: Two cents from 2023: 
input_dir  = r'c:\z_PruebPy\pdf'
output_dir = r'c:\z_PruebPy\output_pdf'

Then:

reader = PdfReader(f'{input_dir}\{fname}')

with open(f'{output_dir}\{fname}', "wb") as pdf_out:

and PyPDF2.errors.DeprecationError: rotate_clockwise is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use rotate instead.

so just:
page.rotate(180)

Comment: @Maciejg thank you for your input I edited this post, haven't tried yet though so I kept original solution as comment.